# Does Qt require closing singelton HTML tags?

Tags: qt, qt5

`QLabel` allows formatting text using HTML tags including "singleton" tags like `<br>` and `<img>`. Should these singletons self-terminate like singletons in XML or should they be treated like void elements in HTML5 (e.g. `<br/>` and `<br>`, respectively)?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's documentation regarding the [supported HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/richtext-html-subset.html) state:

> Qt's text widgets are able to display rich text, specified using a subset of HTML 4 markup. Widgets that use QTextDocument, such as QLabel and QTextEdit, are able to display rich text specified in this way.

Assuming Qt's subset conforms to HTML 4.01 strict, then the correct way to write singletons is to write them **without the trailing forward slash**. That said, HTML4 allows a trailing slash and testing both variants yield the expected result with Qt5.9.

In short, write `<br>` not `</br>`.